# How to create a CRUD WCF service automatically from a EntityFramework data model?

Tags: .net, wcf, entity-framework, windows-8, crud

I have created a data model with EntityFramework 5 and want to use it as a WCF data services. Is there any Framework that can generate this Service automatically out of the DataModel?

Basically I want to save time by not generating every service method by myself. It should support REST and/or SOAP and should generate every possible CRUD-Operation. Is there any good Framework or Tooling for this propose?

As a additional note: The service should be hosted by Microsoft azure later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/odata.aspx). It takes an Entity Framework model and creates a service that uses the OData protocol for querying and modifying the data. Basically, it exposes an EDMX (that's consisted only of the conceptual model part) that any client can use to create simple REST queries with.

There's also a simple permission model for determining what data the service can access and whether it has write access.